# Is there a way to remove the Marker from Routes in Leaflet-Routing-Machine?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using the Leaflet-Routing-Machne for creating a Route between two existing markers, when one clicks them. The problem is, it always adds a marker to the star/end points.

However I want it to be adding no markers.
Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably you are looking for this:

`L.Routing.control({ createMarker: function() { return null; } });`

Reference: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/104